# Programmatically find if current state of git repository is tagged

Tags: git

I'm working on a simple packaging tool that checks that some internal version string (extracted from source code) match a git tag. The goal is to ensure that my program can show it's version number at run time and that this number will be identified by a tag in my repository.

Basically I need to check two things:

- that the repository has no uncommited code at packaging time (empty `git diff`).
- that no commit was done after tagging (`git describe --tags` returns expected tag name)

As it is to be included in a script I understand I should not use git porcelain commands, henceforth I should not parse git diff output or call git describe.

How can I do that only using git plumbing commands ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if the working copy is clean (no uncommitted changes), use [`git status --porcelain`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status), whose output is "remain stable across Git versions and regardless of user configuration." (See the linked man-page for details.)

To see if the currently checked-out revision is the same as the one of the tag you want, you can use [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse): the same hash must be printed by `git rev-parse HEAD` and `git rev-parse $TAGNAME^{}`. The argument is the name of the tag, followed by a caret, then an opening and a closing curly brace; this refers to the commit that is tagged, and not the tag itself (which is also a git object with a hash); for more information on this notation, see [the manpage for `gitrevisions`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html)